# How do I represent integer array as attribute of a class in Visual Studio 2010's UML class diagrams?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, uml

How do I represent integer array as attribute of a class in Visual Studio 2010's UML class diagrams? I know hot to add normal integers, but I'm hoping that there is a way to do it other than adding [] to integer's name.

I'm new to UML, so I could be missing something obvious here.

Should I use Is ordered and Is unique?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would simply indicate the type as Integer and the multiplicity as *.

It is not Ordered. Ordered is for collections that are sorted.

Comment: I meant under class's attributes field. For example I have a class called Producer which has private int[] array; Is there any way to indicate that it is array inside the diagram? Putting [] as part of attribute's name seems a bit stupid to me and I'm hoping that there's another way to do it.

Comment: Oh, sorry. I didn't understand what you meant. You should consider editing your question with this information.

Comment: @mawia: Thanks. It was apparently not obvious to me. Assuming I'm not unique, it may also not be obvious to others.